# How to make text appear in the middle of a phantom in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, calculations, mathtools, phantom

I want to make a part of an equation to appear in the center of a (horizontal) phantom. This would be awesome for example for making [bra-kets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) that are all of the same width and still look natural. This is what I want the result to look like:

[image]

.

I know how to write right- and left-aligned text inside a phantom:

```latex
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{gather*}
    1 + \mathrlap{B}\phantom{ABC} + 2 \\
    1 + \phantom{ABC}\mathllap{B} + 2 \\
    1 + ABC + 2
\end{gather*}
```

I've tried this macro to make a centered text, but it didn't work:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\hmask}[2]{
    \parbox{\widthof{#1}/2}{}
    \mathclap{#2}
    \parbox{\widthof{#1}/2}{}
}

\newcommand{\mask}[2]{\vphantom{#1}\hmask{#1}{#2}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that `\mathclap` should be in math mode.

Comment: Yes, `\mathclap` definitely works in math mode, but it makes a zero-width box with its contents centered on the box. But actually positioning the box to the center of the phantom – that's the hard part.

Comment: You know this, but another alternative is to align at the operators.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't really need to use `\mathclap`, you can just place what you want to center in a box of the appropriate width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand*{\mask}[2]{%
    \mathord{\makebox[\widthof{\(#1\)}]{\(#2\)}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
    1 + \mask{ABC}{B} + 2 \\
    1 + ABC + 2
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

A version that works in all styles.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mask}[2]{{\mathpalette\mask@{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\mask@}[2]{\mask@@{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\mask@@}[3]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen@}{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \makebox[\dimen@]{$\m@th#1#3$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
1 + \mask{ABC}{B} + 2 \\
1 + ABC + 2 \\
1 + \mask{\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx}{y}+2 \\
1 + \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx+2
\end{gather*}

\[
\begin{array}{c}
1 + \mask{\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx}{y}+2 \\
1 + \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx+2
\end{array}
\]

\[
\sum_{\substack{1\le \mask{w}{i}\le n \\ 1\le w\le n}} a_{iw}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]